# Show Google maps offline via service worker.

Tags: javascript, offline, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching

Is there a way to show google maps via the service worker while offline.

I've built a progressive web app that stores all the content and data in the cache via the service worker so it can be accessed offline after use but for the life of me i cant cache google maps then display it.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27922950/1057093). 
Depending on what license you have to use Google Mapts API, you may have to make sure you are [not violating the terms of use](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gmapcatcher/issues/210) by caching the tiles that are not visited(bulk cache of an area without users visiting them)